# How to retrieve Salesforce file attachment limit via API?

Tags: api, salesforce

Salesforce attachment file size is officially limited to 5MB ([doc](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/collab_files_size_limits.htm)) but if requested they can increase this limit on a one to one cases.

My question: Can I retrieve this newly allowed file size limit using the API.

Context: Non-Profits are applying for grants via a web portal (.NET), all data is stored in Salesforce. They are asked to attach files. We read the file size they try to upload and send an error message if it exceeds 5MB as it will not be accepted by Salesforce. This is to avoid having them wait for few minutes to upload to only be told that the file size is too large. We would like to update our code so that it allows files bigger than 5MB if Salesforce allows it. Can we retrieve this information via the API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `getUserInfo()` function in the [SOAP API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo.htm), part of the returned data includes the field `orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit` (this appears to be missing from the docs, but is in the WSDL)

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend going away from Salesforce to store files, more if you'r expecting to hit limits, also there is a limit on the space for storing organization wide, a useful service like Amazon S3 would be very useful, you can then attach the S3 url to your record in case it is needed, it'll be also available for external applications without having to load your org's api consumption.